# template typename question

Tags: c++, templates

I have a problem with template and wondering is there a possible way to achieve what I wanted to do. Here is my question.

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:

    typedef T*              pointer;
    typedef const pointer   const_pointer;

    A()
    {}

    template <typename D>
    A(const D& d)
    {
        // how can I store the D type 
        // so I can refer it later on
        // outside of this function
    }
};
```

ok here is a more complete code of what I wanted to do (it might not be compilable)

```
    class C
{
public:
    virtual ~C(){}

    virtual void* get_d() = 0;
private:

};

template <typename T, typename D>
class Cimpl : public C
{
public:
    Cimpl()
    :t()
    ,d()
    {}

    Cimpl(const T& t, const D& d)
    :t(t)
    ,(d)
    {}

    void* get_d()
    {
        return &reinterpret_cast<D&>(d);
    }

private:
    T t;
    D d;
};

class B
{
public:
    B()
    :p(0)
    {}

    template <typename T, typename D>
    B(const T& t, const D& d)
    :p(0)
    {    
        try
        {
            p = new Cimpl<T, D>(t, d);
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            d(p);
        }
    }

    void* get_d()
    {
        return (p != 0) ? p->get_d() : 0;
    }

    ~B()
    {
      delete p;
    }

private:
    C* p;
};

template <typename T>
class A
{
    struct example_d
    {
    };

public:

    typedef T*              pointer;
    typedef const pointer   const_pointer;

    A()
    {}

    template <typename D>
    A(const T& t)
    :b(t, example_d())
    {
    }

    template <typename D>
    A(const T& t, const D& d)
    :b(t, d)
    {
        // how can I store the D type 
        // so I can refer it later on
        // outside of this function
    }

    // not type safe...as user can cast to any type
    // if I can store the type user pass in previous
    // then I can use it back
    template <typename T>
    T* get_d()
    {
        reinterpret_cast<T*>(b.get_d());
    }

private:
    B b;
};
```

So I can use the class like

```
1)A<int> a(1);// with example_d as D
2)A<int> b(1, another_d()) // with another_d
```

I can change the template to take 2 parameters and use default parameter for 2nd type to be example_d. So I can achieve 1) but not 2). As I will have to code this way

```
A<int, another_d> b(1, another_d());
```

a bit too long to type...

Comment: You can't store a type per se, but there are workarounds.  What do you want to do with D?

Comment: What's the point with the parameter 'T' ? How is it related to the question ?

Comment: I didn't clarify what I wanted to do actually. I want a class only take a single template parameter. Then another template type is supply with the argument constructor. The I'm able to use D type in other part of the class not just where type D is pass in

Comment: 'T' just a random parameter name I chose. It doesn't matter. check my above comment

Comment: Ok I update the post with code of what actually wanted to do.

Comment: With that update, now your situation is even more impossible. Not only do you want to "store" the type (which you can't do), you want the parameter passed to the constructor of a class to modify the return type of one of its members. The only sane answers to this question are multiple class template parameters or subclassing.

Comment: I think I would need rtti here...just change get_d to take type_info then in the Cimpl class compare the pass in type_info with D if equal then cast else return 0...

Comment: @stephenteh: RTTI in C++ isn't powerful enough to do what you want. From quickly looking at your code it seems you are indeed storing `d` - only you do it through a layer (`B`) which eliminates all type information. That's your problem.

Comment: @sbi: if I'm using rtti that will achieve what I needed actually as the only problem I encounter is get_d is not type safe as user can pass in one type but call get_d with difference type. By having type_info pass in as argument for get_d then I can do the type comparison at Cimpl class of get_d, if it is same type then I will do the casting else return 0 as the user need to check the return value. Thanks for your reply :-)

Comment: @stephenteh: And if you templatify `B::get_d()`, you can do this without RTTI...

Comment: @sbi: Yes only if get_d is not a virtual function.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot store a type, you can only store objects.

(If you want to store the parameter `d` passed to `A`'s constructor, look at [type erasure](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html).)

Answer (score 2):

You can't "save" a typename like that. What you really want to do is make type D one of the template parameters of the class, e.g.

```
template <typename T, typename D>
class A
{
public:

    typedef T*              pointer;
    typedef const pointer   const_pointer;

    A()
    {}

    A(const D& d)
    {
    }
};
```

Now, if your problem is that you want `A<T>` constructed with type `D` to be polymorphic with `A<T>` constructed with type `E` instead of having `A<T,D>` and `A<T,E>` be two different types, then the solution is a base class:

```
template <typename T>
class ABase
{
public:

    typedef T*              pointer;
    typedef const pointer   const_pointer;

    ABase()
    {}

protected:

    /* You might want to omit this constructor completely, 
     * depending on your use case */

    template<typename D>
    ABase(const D& d)
    {
    }
};

template <typename T, typename D>
class A : public ABase<T>
{
public:

    A()
    {}

    A(const D& d)
      : ABase(d)
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you are trying to create a template class that has a [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/any.html) member variable.  You should look at this a possible way of doing this.

Basically a `boost::any` can accept any value type.  You can then retrieve that type safely if you know the type later.  A good example of how you would use this is to store different datatypes in a map, (where you know the type later when you retrieve the the any by its name).

If this is not exactly what you are looking for the internals use a neat trick to implement it, and it will probably help you achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use type D in other member functions of class A, you can make D a second template parameter of class A.

Comment: actually I knew this but I only need one template parameter for the class. So wondering is there a way to do. thanks

Comment: Is there any reason why you absolutely can't have two template parameters?  If that's the case, you can derive A from another class Abase, which would take D as its template parameter.

Comment: @stephenteh: How about you telling us what you want to store `D` for?

Comment: Usually you don't want `D` as a template argument, because you want argument deduction to kick in so you don't have to spell it out.